# JavaFX Access nodes inside ScrollPane by FX:ID

Tags: java, math, javafx, scrollpane

One of my projects with JavaFX has a settings window with an ScrollPane in it. There I have all the checkboxes, input fields and sliders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox?>
    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSlider?>
    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane?>
    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
    <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

    <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
       <children>
          <JFXTabPane rotateGraphic="true" side="BOTTOM">
             <tabs>
                <Tab closable="false" styleClass="container" text="%settings.tab.main">
                  <content>
                      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="20.0" styleClass="container">
                         <children>
                            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.language" />
                                  <JFXComboBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.language" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.window.width" />
                                  <JFXSlider majorTickUnit="50.0" max="1049.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" min="850.0" minorTickCount="10" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="210.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.window.height" />
                                  <JFXSlider majorTickUnit="50.0" max="900.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" min="500.0" minorTickCount="10" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0">
                               <children>
                                  <JFXCheckBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.window.maximized" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                         </children>
                         <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
                         </padding>
                      </VBox>
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab closable="false" styleClass="container" text="%settings.tab.exercises">
                   <content>
                      <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefViewportHeight="593.0" prefViewportWidth="600.0">
                         <content>
                            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="20.0" styleClass="container">
                               <children>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.add.ex" />
                                        <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.add" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.add.min" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.add.max" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.sub.ex" />
                                        <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.sub" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.sub.min" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.sub.max" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.mul.ex" />
                                        <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.mul" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.mul.min" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.mul.max" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.div.ex" />
                                        <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.div" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.div.min" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.div.max" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label disable="true" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.power.ex" />
                                        <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.power" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.power.min.base" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.power.max.base" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label disable="true" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.roots.ex" />
                                        <HBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.roots" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.roots.min.rad" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.roots.max.rad" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <HBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="37.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                           <children>
                                              <JFXCheckBox disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="150.0" text="%settings.roots.dec" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.roots.min.expo" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                              <JFXTextField disable="true" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="%settings.roots.max.expo" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                           </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="10.0">
                                     <children>
                                        <Label maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.count" />
                                     </children>
                                  </VBox>
                               </children>
                               <padding>
                                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
                               </padding>
                            </VBox>
                         </content>
                      </ScrollPane>
                   </content>
                </Tab>
             </tabs>
          </JFXTabPane>
       </children>
       <padding>
          <Insets top="50.0" />
       </padding>
    </StackPane>
```

To set the default value of these nodes I want the Java code to access each element with its FX:ID.

```
package handlers;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSlider;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSnackbar;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;

import initializers.InitSettings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import resources.lang.Locales;
import settings.Settings;
import resources.lang.Language;

public class SettingsHandler {

    private static Scene scene;

    public static void setDefault(Scene scene) {
        SettingsHandler.scene = scene;

//      Replace the checkboxes' values with the values from the settings file (true or false)
        setCheckboxValue("add", Settings.add);
        setCheckboxValue("sub", Settings.sub);
        setCheckboxValue("mul", Settings.mul);
        setCheckboxValue("div", Settings.div);
        setCheckboxValue("subNeg", Settings.subNeg);
        setCheckboxValue("divDec", Settings.divComma);
        setCheckboxValue("windowMaximized", Settings.startMaximized);
        setCheckboxValue("automaticUpdates", Settings.automaticUpdates);

    private static void setCheckboxValue(String selector, boolean value) {
        ((JFXCheckBox) scene.lookup("#" + selector)).setSelected(value);
    }
}
```

But Java can't find the elements.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at handlers.SettingsHandler.setCheckboxValue(SettingsHandler.java:141)
    at handlers.SettingsHandler.setDefault(SettingsHandler.java:30)
    at initializers.InitSettings.init(InitSettings.java:25)
    at initializers.InitMain$2.handle(InitMain.java:66)
    at initializers.InitMain$2.handle(InitMain.java:60)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

All of my search queries on Google couldn't give me the right information. I just got more and more tutorials of how to create a ScrollPane. So I'm asking you: How can I access the elements inside the ScrollPane.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm just being blind, but I can't see where you have given your `JFXCheckbox` Nodes an id, e.g. `fx:id="checkboxOne"`. `lookup()` will search for an id. "If no nodes are found with this id, then null is returned." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#lookup-java.lang.String-

Comment: @d.j.brown The checkboxes are given in the first code snippet. 
`<VBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0">
                               <children>
                                  <JFXCheckBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="%settings.window.maximized" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>`

Comment: @d.j.brown My problem is that I can access all the nodes apart from these ones INSIDE the ScrollPane and I don't understand why!

Comment: try `scene.lookup("scrollPaneToFind").getContent().lookup("checkBoxToFind");` Nodes inside a `ScrollPane` are content rather than children it would seem.

Comment: @KingOfDog: Just search for `id=` in your post. There is not a single match, let alone a match for `fx:id=`!

Comment: @d.j.brown Thanks, you answered my question!

Answer (score 1):

The content simply has not been added to the scene graph, since the `ScrollPane` has not been layouted and therefore the `skin` that would add the `ScrollPane` content to the scene graph has not yet been created.

This code demonstrates this behaviour:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle content = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    content.setId("id");
    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(content);

    System.out.println("before: "+sp.lookup("#id")); // null

    Scene scene = new Scene(sp);

    // do layout (sp needs to be added to a scene for this to work)
    sp.applyCss();
    sp.layout();

    System.out.println("after: "+sp.lookup("#id")); // non-null

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

It's a bad idea to identify the nodes using `lookup` in most cases anyway. Better use a controller or at least use the [`namespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getNamespace--) of the `FXMLLoader` instance used to load the fxml to access the objects using the `fx:id`s.

**Note:** It would also probably be helpful to actually specify the `fx:id` attributes in the fxml file. Otherwise you won't find any matches even after layout.